# Displaying two graphs adjacent to each other with their x-axes aligned

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do I align the following two graphs so that their x-axes are aligned?  In both graphs, the top of the y-axis is higher than I want.  It seems to be at a height between 13 and 14.  How do I get them to a height of 11?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=3in,axis equal image,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-4,xmax=8,samples=101,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-2,ymax=10,
    restrict y to domain=-2:10,
    enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={2,10},ytick={},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot [latex-latex,domain=-4:8] {x + 2} node [pos=0.9, anchor=north west, font=\footnotesize] {$y=f(x)$};
\draw [fill=white] (2,4) circle [radius=1.5pt] node[right,font=\tiny]{$(2, \, 4)$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=3in,axis equal image,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-4,xmax=8,samples=101,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-2,ymax=10,
    restrict y to domain=-2:10,
    enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={2,10},ytick={},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot [latex-latex,domain=-4:8] {x + 2} node [pos=0.9, anchor=north west, font=\footnotesize] {$y=g(x)$};
\draw [fill=white] (2,4) circle [radius=1.5pt] node[right,font=\tiny]{$(2, \, 4)$};
\draw [fill] (2,0) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the max y values to be identical eliminate the `enlargelimits` and specify the desired `ymax=11` for both graphs:

[image]

### Notes:

- To get the two graphs to be next to each other, you need to eliminate the blank line between the `\end{tikzpicture}` and `\begin{tikzpicture}`.
- This also necessitated adding a `left` option to the placement of the graph label.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=3in,axis equal image,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-4,xmax=8,samples=101,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-2,ymax=11,
    restrict y to domain=-2:10,
    %enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={2,10},ytick={},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot [latex-latex,domain=-4:8] {x + 2} node [pos=0.9, anchor=north west, font=\footnotesize, left] {$y=f(x)$};
\draw [fill=white] (2,4) circle [radius=1.5pt] node[right,font=\tiny]{$(2, \, 4)$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=3in,axis equal image,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-4,xmax=8,samples=101,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-2,ymax=11,
    restrict y to domain=-2:10,
   % enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={2,10},ytick={},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot [latex-latex,domain=-4:8] {x + 2} node [pos=0.9, anchor=north west, font=\footnotesize, left] {$y=g(x)$};
\draw [fill=white] (2,4) circle [radius=1.5pt] node[right,font=\tiny]{$(2, \, 4)$};
\draw [fill] (2,0) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Those _y_-axes [go to 11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_to_eleven)! `;-)`

Comment: @PaulGessler: That's a pretty subtle reference. :-)

Comment: @Paul Gessler I know it is a joke.  Are you saying that looking at just the y-axes from a distance, it could look like "11"?  Is "go to 11" an allusion to limit?

Comment: @Adelyn: It is a movie reference.

Comment: @Peter Grill  What movie, and what is the line in the movie?  Do you see the pun in the question?